# Pig Latin Program Java, problems with vowel inputs

Tags: java

This is my attempt at a simple Pig Latin Word Translator in Java.  If the word starts with a consonant, the consonant is moved to the end of the word and "ay" is added.  If the word starts with a vowel then way is added to the end of the word.  I have difficulty understanding as to why my program is having issues with vowels.

Example:

apple is translated to ppleaay instead of appleway
Yet, van is translated to anvay as it should.

```
public class PigLatin 
{
    public static String translate (String original) {
        String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
        String latin = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (original.charAt(0) == vowels.charAt(i)) {
                latin = original + "way";
            }else {
                latin = original.substring(1) + original.charAt(0) + "ay";
            }
        }
        return latin;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("What is the word to be translated: ");
        String origWord = IO.readString();
        String newWord = translate(origWord);
        System.out.print("The translated word is: " + newWord);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about words which begin with a consonant _syllable_, but which contains more than one consonant?  E.g. `chameleon` would become `ameleonchay`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Pig Latin isn't a real language anyway. I'd assume *hameloncay* is acceptable.

Comment: This is a mistake a lot of new programmers make... Your code to add `"ay"` should not be executed until you've checked _all_ the vowels.  Therefore, that code has to be outside the loop (after the loop is done), not inside it.

Comment: have you tried to run debugger with your code? Use step-by-step debugging and inspect your variables upon every step to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: I've tried running debugger, I'm not completely sure how to use it, I'm still learning however I know that it's extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `if` is inside of the `for` loop. You want that the `else` branch is only executed if the first character is neither `'a'` nor `'e'` nor `'i'` etc.

This is a simpler way to get the correct result:

```
public static String translate(String original) {
    switch (original.toLowerCase().charAt(0)) { // transform to lowercase to simplify code
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            return original + "way";
        default:
            return original.substring(1) + original.charAt(0) + "ay";
    }
}
```

If you have to transform uppercase words properly:

```
public static String translate(String original) {
    switch (original.toLowerCase().charAt(0)) { // transform to lowercase to simplify code
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            return original + "way";
        default:
            if (original.charAt(0) >= 'a' || original.length() == 1) {
                // lowercase word or word with only 1 character
                return original.substring(1) + original.charAt(0) + "ay";
            } else {
                // uppercase, at least 2 characters
                String first = "" + original.charAt(0);
                String second = "" + original.charAt(1);
                String rest = original.substring(2);
                return second.toUpperCase() + rest + first.toLowerCase() + "ay";
            }
    }
}
```

I assumed that the input has at least one character.

Comment: Your reasoning does not appear to be correct and a switch is less than optimal for this case. Why does your full example have an `if` stamement in the `default` case?

Comment: the if is necessary because of uppercase and lowercase words (word -> ordway, Word -> Ordway, etc.)

Comment: About the switch statement: a switch is a great solution in this case, because it doesn't require a loop. A switch is usually implemented with a lookup table which is a lot faster than an if inside a loop. Apart from that, it's more intuitive. You can see immediately what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will loop through every single vowel without stopping when it finds a match. Basically, the last test is the only one that will matter, and since `apple` does not start with `U`, you get the unexpected result.

There are a couple of ways of dealing with this. One is to terminate the loop early if you find a match. You can use a break, but a `return` would be better. The reason is that you will end up constructing a bunch of useless results along the way for non-matching characters otherwise. Here is an example using `return`:

```
public static String translate (String original) {
    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (original.charAt(0) == vowels.charAt(i)) {
            return original + "way";
        }
    }
    return original.substring(1) + original.charAt(0) + "ay";
}
```

Another, probably better way would be check if the first character of your word is in the list of vowels using one of the built-in `String` methods instead of reinventing the wheel. A couple of obvious options are [`String.indexOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) and [`String.contains(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-). Here are examples of how to use these methods:

```
public static String translate (String original) {
    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    if(vowels.contains(original.substring(0, 1))) {
        return original + "way";
    }
    return original.substring(1) + original.charAt(0) + "ay";
}
```

or

```
public static String translate (String original) {
    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    if(vowels.indexOf(original.charAt(0)) >= 0) {
        return original + "way";
    }
    return original.substring(1) + original.charAt(0) + "ay";
}
```

As @Aloso pointed out, you may want to handle the case where your `original` string begins with an uppercase letter a bit differently. For example, you would probably want `Van` to become `Anvay`, not `anVay`. I would recommend using the [`isUpperCase(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase-char-), `toUpperCase(char)` and [`toLowerCase(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase-char-) methods of the [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class rather than messing with ASCII codes. If you need this functionality, replace the line `return original.substring(1) + original.charAt(0) + "ay";` with the following in any of the examples above:

```
if(Character.isUpperCase(original.charAt(0))) {
    return Character.toUpperCase(original.charAt(1)) + original.substring(2) + Character.toLowerCase(original.charAt(0)) + "ay";
}
return original.substring(1) + original.charAt(0) + "ay";
```

Using the methods in `Character` also means that your strings will behave properly even if you enter non-Latin characters. Although is it really pig-Latin in that case?